# Xsl.LoadException was unhandled

Tags: c#, xslt

For some reason, when i try to load the xslt file, i get this compile error

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.Xsl.XslLoadException' occurred in System.Data.SqlXml.dll"

I know it something wrong with the xslt file, but Inspect the xslt file, i dont see where the error would be at.

this is the code to transform , and the xslt that i used.

```
        XslCompiledTransform XmlTransformFile;
        XmlTransformFile = new XslCompiledTransform();
        XmlTransformFile.Load(hotelXslFilename);   // xsl file name,
        XmlTransformFile.Transform(HotelItemsFilename, ReportFilename);   // xml file,  with new Html file


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result- prefixes="msxsl">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
<title>Hotels in the Key West Area</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hotels in the Key West Area</h1>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Rating</th>
          <th>Average Price per Night</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select ="ArrayOfHotelListItems/HotelListItems">
          <tr>
            <td><xsl:apply-templates select="Name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:apply-templates select="Rating"/></td>
            <td>
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <xsl:for-each select="./Rooms">
                    <td>
                    <div class="room">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="Room"/>
                    </td>
                    </div>
                  </xsl:for-each>            
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>               
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Name">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Rating">
 <!--TODO: Obtain rating pics from Web and use case statement to apply to ratings-->
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="Rating = 5">
    <img src="./5stars.png">
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="Rating = 4.5">
    <img src="./45stars.png">
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="Rating = 4">
    <img src="./4stars.png">
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="Rating = 3.5">
    <img src="./35stars.png">
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="Rating = 3">
    <img src="./3stars.png">
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="Rating = 2.5">
    <img src="./25stars.png">
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="Rating = 2">
    <img src="./2stars.png">
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="Rating = 1.5">
    <img src="./15stars.png">
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Room">
<xsl:value-of select="./RoomType"/> = $<xsl:value-of select="./Rate"/>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You have multiple syntax errors. Try using this tool: http://xsltransform.net/bFWR5E1

Comment: thanks, that site was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML isn't HTML, your `img` tags are not closed. You're also closing your `div` and `td` tags in the wrong order.

Generally speaking, you should check the `InnerException` of an `XslLoadException`, it contains the `XmlException` that details the problems with your XML.

When you're using the HTML output method, `img` tags are output unclosed as this is perfectly valid HTML, but your stylesheet must be valid XML.

Comment: yea i went thru it again, and notice that. Thanks for the help